# Liunx based Azure PHP App service is missing MYSQL Driver

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

I'm trying to host WordPress website on Azure Linux App service.

I got this error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I searched everywhere but I didn't find how to install the MYSQL driver to Liunx based Azure PHP App service.

What I know that I have to do some changes to an `ini` file; But I don't know how.

### Update

I already tried to install mysql using:

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

I got this error

[image: SSH screenshoot]

When I tried:

```
 yum install php-mysqlnd
```

I got this error:
[image: SSH screenshoot2]

### Update 2

The command 
`apt-cache search php` 
Shows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Re: your update, there are various package names - it may be something like `php7-mysqlnd` or the like. Try `apt-cache search mysql | grep php` to see potential options. FYI, your PHP version, 5.6, is [outdated and no longer receives security updates](https://php.net/eol.php). You should update to [a supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) ASAP.

Comment: Azure isn't allowing me to do any installation on app server using `apt-get` and `apt-cache search mysql | grep php` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz regarding the php version you are right and thanks for your advice. But It isn't related to the issue. It tried also with PHP 7 and got same problem.

Comment: Then start with `apt-cache search php` and start from there.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm sorry but it isn't a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've repeatedly failed to provide the requisite info to provide a solution.

Comment: @ceejayoz which info? I'm using very normal azure app service. If you know how to solve the issue please provide the steps and thanks for you help attempts.

Comment: You continue to just say stuff like "isn't a solution", "isn't working", etc. without any details of what that means. What did `apt-cache search php` show? Were there any MySQL packages listed in its output?

Comment: I posted an update hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Read the part about enabling PHP extensions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php

Navigate to the web SSH session with your Linux container (https://cephalin-container.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host).

Based on Linux Distro either:
apt-get install php-mysql 
or
yum install php-mysqlnd

You could try adding another repository.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

then update:

sudo apt-get update

then run the install command again

Comment: where to get the .so files?

Comment: You have to ssh into your container.

Navigate to the web SSH session with your Linux container (https://cephalin-container.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host).

Depending on your linux distribution you either use:

apt-get install php-mysql or yum install php-mysqlnd

Comment: You could try adding another repository.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

then update: 

sudo apt-get update

then run the install command again

Comment: `sudo` itself isn't allowed.